# How can I detect whether a Mac has a Retina display from Java?

Tags: java, macos

I've found a Swing image rendering bug which afflicts only Macs with Retina displays (`TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE` `BufferedImages` fail to draw). I have an effective workaround (use `TYPE_INT_ARGB` images instead), but in order to apply it, I need to be able to detect whether the host machine is a Mac with a Retina display. Detecting whether the machine is a Mac is no problem, but how can I determine the display type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("apple.awt.contentScaleFactor")`

The above line should return `2.0` on retina displays. On more recent non-retina macs it returns `1.0` and on all other platforms you get back `null`. I can't find any official documentation, but I ran across it [in this mailing list post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Jul/msg00048.html) while trying to solve a similar problem.

Comment: This is not a good method because users may have multiple monitors, one of which is Retina and one which isn't. You need to query this state for individual windows each time you repaint.

Comment: This returns null on my late 2013 rMBP. Is there somewhere specific it should be used?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://osdir.com/ml/macosx-port-development-java/2013-11/msg00118.html) solution which uses:

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics ();
boolean retinaTest = g.getFontRenderContext ().getTransform ()
    .equals (AffineTransform.getScaleInstance (2.0, 2.0));
```